# Network breaks due to one PC, no idea why

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

I have a PC with GIGABYTE B550M AORUS PRO-P motherboard with integrated Realtek 2.5Gbps network card. Suddenly I start getting network breaks, meaning everything breaks, including router’s connection to outside world. I assume it’s due to router, or ISP, so I get a new router. Same thing happens. Finally I figure out it’s the PC and unplugging the network cable for a moment helps.

By “network breaks” I mean the router disconnects from the WAN Ethernet, no machine in the LAN can connect to another, everything just stops working. Router keeps asking for DHCP in the logs but no answer, until I disconnect this PC for a second. Then everything works again, including the PC.

Even if I connect a switch between the router and this PC instead of connecting it directly to the router this happens. It may happen once in three days, or twice a day. More often if I’m moving lots of data (4K movies, for example), but it’s not consistent even with this.

If I run Wireshark on the PC it shows nothing flooding, nothing out of the ordinary. Just some ARP requests that never get answers. Same from another machine in the network. Nothing just works.

The two routers also were from different manufacturers and very different in every way, so it shouldn’t be some issue with certain chips or firmware. Switch shows no activity during this outage.

No other PC in the network causes any issues, just this one. What could be the cause for this extremely weird issue and how to solve it or even start to diagnose outside of what I’ve tried?

Comment: any firmware updates from the mobo manufacturer related to the NIC?

Comment: Can you replace the network card?   Also check your computer for viruses including root kit viruses.

Comment: Once had a *very* unusual network issue, where one PC would bring down a whole segment of the Ethernet LAN. Turned out the PC was using the wrong 802.1x packet type, and others in the system had automatic packet type recognition on. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/802-1x-authentication-issues-troubleshooting and https://howiwifi.com/2020/07/19/wireless-802-1x-troubleshooting/ . Admittedly, this is not a common issue.

Comment: @Keltari No, latest BIOS installed, all drivers latest also